# Android google map v2 auto update

Tags: google-maps, maps, android-maps-v2

Hi i need marker update at time i try do it

```
ArrayList<LatLng> markerList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_soc_map);

    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    markerList.add(new LatLng(48.8742, 2.3470));
    markerList.add(new LatLng(0, 0));

Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){

    GetDataFromWeb GDFW = new GetDataFromWeb();

       public void run() {


         for (LatLng latLon : markerList) {
         mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLon).title("Another marker"));
            }
           //GDFW.execute();                       
       }

    }, 12000, 12000);

}
```

so.. i take from database Lat and Lng but i just test with

```
markerList.add(new LatLng(48.8742, 2.3470));
markerList.add(new LatLng(0, 0));
```

so.. i need after 12s take Lat and Lag and update map marker

I have not found anywhere answer so maybe you can help me:)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have just got the same problem and solved it.

```
public class Livebus extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.googlemaps);

        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mTask = (GetDataFromWeb) new GetDataFromWeb().execute(); //This is an AsyncTaskClass
    }


class GetDataFromWeb extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

       protected String doInBackground(String... param) {

           while(true)
           {
               //HERE You should collect your data from the Web
               latitude=...
               longitude=...

               //You have to update the markers in the Main thread which is also called UI thread.
               //AsyncTask classes create theit own thread so you need to run the marker 
               //update on the UI thread. Which you can see below now.

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                   public void run() {
                       mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                       .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                       .title("Hello"));
                   }
               });
           }
     }
}
```

This is my first answer here I hope it helps you :)
If something doesn't work pls contact me I will get it working.

Details on AsyncTasks: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
Details on the threads: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Read that I also learnt my lesson today.